# How to pass locale to a Minitest Integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, minitest

Trying to pass to a literal pathname doesn't work.

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class Info::AccountPendingControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get index" do
    get '/account-pending', locale: 'en'
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal "index", @controller.action_name
    assert_equal "account_pending", @controller.controller_name
  end
end
```

Result

```
ERROR["test_should_get_index", Minitest::Result, 0.21732900000642985]
 test_should_get_index#Minitest::Result (0.22s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: unknown keyword: locale
            test/controllers/info/account_pending_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:AccountPendingControllerTest>'
```

So how can we pass in locale for a non-logged in user, at the test level?

Answer (score 0):

Helper document https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/get.

2nd argument is

> parameters: The HTTP parameters that you want to pass. This may be nil, a Hash, or a String that is appropriately encoded (application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data).

Try the code below.

```
  test "should get index" do
    get '/account-pending', nil, {HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en'}
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal "index", @controller.action_name
    assert_equal "account_pending", @controller.controller_name
  end
```